# getting fscanf to store in structs in C

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have an assignment where I need to get Values of RLC circuits from a file and calculate the resonant frequency however my issue is when I use the fscanf function it reads only the first line of the file and the rest comes out as zeros .

```
#include <stdio.h>
data

 int h;
typedef struct cct
{
  int code[50];
  float R[50];
  float L[50];
  float C[50];
} CCT;

 int read(CCT cct[], int n_p, FILE* fp){
   char temp;

   if(fp==NULL){
       printf("Error\n");
       return -1;
   }
   fscanf(fp,"%d,%f,%e,%e\n", cct[n_p].code, cct[n_p].R,cct[n_p].L, &cct[n_p].C);

}
int main()
{
   FILE* fp = fopen("U://datafile.txt", "rt");
   int i = 0;
   CCT cct[50];
   int size;

   while (!feof(fp)) {
       read(cct, i, fp);
       i++;
   }
   size = i;

   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     printf("%d,%0.2f,%0.2f,%0.2f\n", cct[i].code[i], cct[i].R[i],
            cct[i].L[i], cct[i].C[i]);

 scanf("%d",&h);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

and this is the data file

```
    1,4.36,2.23e-2,4.65e-8
    2,4.57,2.01e-2,5.00e-8
    3,3.99,2.46e-2,4.82e-8
    4,4.09,2.60e-2,4.70e-8
```

I would appreciate if someone could point put why it only gets the first line. Thanks

Comment: I would used `fgets()` into a string buffer, and then use sscanf() on the string instead of `fscanf()`  It tends to work more reliably.

Comment: John would you mind explaining that to me as I am new to programming thanks.

Comment: Do you want `CCT cct[50];` ? or `CCT cct;`

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. `fscanf` will read just the first element of each array field of struct cct. If you have 50 of each `code`, `R`, `L`, `C` in each of 50 `cct`s then you have some kind of rectangular table of values, and you are reading just the first column. Then you are printing `cct[i].code[i]` which are *diagonal* elements. This cannot possibly be right.

Comment: @n.m. I am trying to get each set of values alone so I can use them to make calculations so in the End I get a sort of code and frequency table.

Comment: I don't understand what "each set of values alone" mean. Do you have a two-dimensional table of values?

Comment: BTW: for `fscanf()`, `"%f"`,`"%e"` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(fp,"%d,%f,%e,%e", cct[n_p].code, cct[n_p].R,cct[n_p].L, cct[n_p].C);
...
printf("%d,%0.2f,%0.2f,%0.2f\n", cct[i].code[0], cct[i].R[0], cct[i].L[0], cct[i].C[0]);
```

---

Something like the following, perhaps

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct cct {
  int code;
  float R;
  float L;
  float C;
} CCT;

int h;

int read(CCT cct[], int n_p, FILE* fp){
   char temp;

   if(fp==NULL){
       printf("Error\n");
       return -1;
   }
   fscanf(fp,"%d,%f,%e,%e\n", &cct[n_p].code, &cct[n_p].R, &cct[n_p].L, &cct[n_p].C);
}
int main(){
   FILE* fp = fopen("U://datafile.txt", "rt");
   int i = 0;
   CCT cct[50];
   int size;

   while (!feof(fp)) {
       read(cct, i, fp);
       i++;
   }
   size = i;

   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     printf("%d,%0.2f,%0.2f,%0.2f\n", cct[i].code, cct[i].R, cct[i].L, cct[i].C);
scanf("%d",&h);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you It worked would you please explain to me why? thanks again

Comment: @user3570628 , `fscanf(fp,"%d,%f,%e,%e", cct[n_p].code, cct[n_p].R...` meant `fscanf(fp,"%d,%f,%e,%e", &cct[n_p].code[0], &cct[n_p].R[0]...`

Answer (score 0):

CCT is composed of multiple arrays (you have arrays of arrays, which is wrong for the exercise, but that's not the point) and you always write to the element zero of the arrays. For example, cct[n_p].code in fscanf() is the address of the array, which is identical to the address of cct[n_p].code[0]. Then you print code[i] in the output loop, which is blank except for i == 0.